# NoScrollExpandableListView inside NestedScrollView is slow

Tags: java, android

```
<ConstraintLayout>
   <Toolbar></Toolbar>
    <NestedScrollView fillViewport="true" isScrollContainer="true">
       <ConstraintLayout>
          <ImageView></ImageView>
          <TextView></TextView>
          <NoScrollExpandableListView width="match_parent" height="wrap_content"/>
       </ConstraintLayout>
    </NestedScrollView>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

The above code is working as expected but NoScrollExpandableListView has onMeasure() which is being called multiple times or so which is making item expand on click delay.

I am looking either to achieve the entire scroll without NoScrollExpandableListView or if someone can help in improving the NoScrollExpandableListView implementation to avoid slowness and more efficient.

Please, do help it is something I am stuck with and not able to find a solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try property

```
android:nestedScrollEnabled="false"
```

In the xml for NoScrollExpandableListView view.

Comment: The scroll is not an issue @paras. The issue is the delay in expanding the child when a clicked parent. So, if the entire screen scroll can be achieved without NoScrollExpandableListView then will be fast.